# Unable to resolve "firebase" from "src\containers\Login.js"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I got this error when i run the exp start command. How can I solve this error?

This is my `login.js` file code.
I am new to React native, using js to run a native app using expo, so I am stuck. I don't know why it gives me this error and how to handle it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  AsyncStorage,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Dimensions,
  ActivityIndicator,
  NetInfo,
  BackHandler,
  DeviceEventEmitter
} from 'react-native';


import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import firebaseService from '../config/firebaseService';

import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Modal from "react-native-modal";

import { Dialog,ConfirmDialog } from 'react-native-simple-dialogs';

import Toast, {DURATION} from 'react-native-easy-toast';
import Expo from 'expo';

var height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

import styles from "../styles/loginStyle";
import {apiUrl,netErrorMsg,facebookId,androidGoogleClientId,iosGoogleClientId,firebaseConfig} from "../config/constant";


export default class Login extends Component<{}> {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
        this.state = {
          email:'',
          password:'',
          forgotEmail:'',
          versionName:'',
          loading:false,
          isModalVisible: false,
          netStatus:'none',
          dialogVisible:false,
          errorForgotEmail:""
        }

    }
```

Comment: Share  the code from where the `firebase` is referenced from 'src\containers\Login.js'

Comment: Now i solved that problem now it's gives me this error Unable to resolve "scheduler/tracing" from "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js"

Comment: did you ever get this working, im getting your same oringinal issue: Unable to resolve "../config/firebaseSDK" from "components/Login.js"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to import `firebase` from your `Login.js` in some file. Remove that import and import firebase as you have imported it in your `Login.js`. This will resolve the problem.

Comment: Now i solved that problem now it's gives me this error Unable to resolve "scheduler/tracing" from "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js"

Comment: Refresh you node_modules, `rm -rf node_modules` and then `yarn install`/`npm install` and then start your packager with no previous cache using `npm start --reset-cache`

Comment: when install npm then it's show this warninig npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})